# why does a multicast server endlessly transmitting packets even no client require

Tags: networking, bandwidth, multicast, streaming, video-streaming

i used to setup a multicast server using windows server 2003 OS, i can see a lot of packets transimitted from the server once it was started. Does it make sense when no one is requiring the multicast stream? Isn't the network bandwidth wasted ?

Comment: What are you multicasting? How have you configured it? What application is doing the multicasting? Why are you using a server OS that goes end of support in 1 year?

Comment: i am multicasting video stream.Default configuration, not quite remember the app doing the multicasting.For the __OS__, it is just what i only have among my virtual machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.  Multicast is a function of routing, so that a client can add itself to a multicast group and traffic will be routed its way.

The server isn't likely acting as a router with regards to IGMP and of course it has no idea if anyone is subscribed or not.  However, it would be perfectly legitimate (and advisable) for the first hop router to discard the traffic.